# Octopress blog deploying error - No such file or directory - public/_posts/build/cssselect/.coveragerc

Tags: rake, octopress

Suddenly I am getting this error when running rake deploy. How do I fix this? Rake preview works fine. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
~/dev/octopress$ rake deploy
## Found posts in preview mode, regenerating files ...
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css
Configuration from /home/me/dev/octopress/_config.yml
Building site: source -> public
Successfully generated site: source -> public
cp -r source/_posts/build/cssselect/.coveragerc public/_posts/build/cssselect/.coveragerc
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - public/_posts/build/cssselect/.coveragerc

Tasks: TOP => copydot
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: This seems rather odd... what is in source/_posts/build??

Comment: @tamouse https://gist.github.com/staticaland/2691d3d7fc9dd992a0a8 Here you go. Would be amazing if you see something :)

Comment: Okay, I am completely unsure of why you have that build directory under _posts. _posts is where you write your posts. I don't even *see* any posts in there. Did you try to install something in there? Or is your configuration off? I don't really know what that is doing there. If you haven't written anything yet, my suggestion is to start over with a fresh install of OP.

Comment: I created a new project and it works, thanks! I have no idea why or what happened tbh.